# Why are my ratings in Windows Media Player only partially applied?

Tags: windows-media-player, rating

I want to rate media in my library but those ratings are being applied only partially to my files themselves.

Please note that I want to do this for all kinds of media, not only music.

Comment: Oh, the ratings are stored in the metadata properties, not the ID3 tag, my bad... What do you mean by partially? Do some files not work or do files of a specific type not work?

Comment: i have only tried it with movies. i cannot recognise any pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>**ALT**</kbd>, then go to **Tools** > **Options** > **Library**.

How is the bottom option set there? Have you tried toggling that setting?

[image]

Comment: but i want to do this for all kinds of media, not only music.

Comment: @elluca: I've adjusted my answer with a new suggestion.

Comment: yes, i have tried that. it did process my library, but still only a party of my files is being rated.